# Bakeoff Part 2: Math with Cython Typed Memoryviews

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython, lda

I can't seem to do simple things like add a value to an array of values stored in a memory view. I understand that is not what a typed memory view is supposed to do. But converting the memory view back to an np.array is slower than tortoises herding cats.

When I try to write a cdef function like:

```
cdef double[::1] _add(self,double[::1] arr,double val):
  cdef double[::1] newarr
  cdef int i, n
  #n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
  newarr = np.empty(5)
  for i in xrange(n):
    newarr[i] = arr[i] + val
    return newarr
```

I get errors that say that the memoryviews are not contiguous.

> "ValueError: Buffer and memoryview are not contiguous in the same dimension."

This actually does work if the memory view that is passed is not one that has been sliced. But it adds 10 seconds to the process!

Comment: Your `return` looks like it's indented wrong. (Not the problem, but possibly a problem)

Comment: You are right - I made a mistake, but i seem to have fixed later - continue to get compile error.